# ArcGIS Select Tool: Do Not Create Empty Feature Class

Tags: arcgis-desktop, convert, select, arctoolbox

I am creating an ArcGIS Model that imports a number of Bentley .dgn files to a geodatabase.  My workflow involves:

1. Running the CAD to Geodatabase Tool, which brings all the drawing features into a feature dataset.
2. Taking the feature types and then selecting features by the "layer" attribute and writing them to a feature class with an appropriate name.

My issue occurs at the Select tool.  It will create a feature class even if it did not find any features to place in the feature class.  This creates a whole bunch of empty feature classes since there are a number of layers which may or may not show up in any of my .dgns.  So, I would like to know if there is a way to keep my model from creating blank feature classes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [Get Count Management tool](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgiSDEsktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=get_count_%28data_management%29) described in the link and create a condition that prevents the creation of a feature class unless it returns a non-0 number.

The above link is for ArcGIS 9.3. If you are using 10, [the documentation here](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//0017000000n7000000.htm) is more appropriate.